# Wordpress redirects to a certain path

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, permalinks

After moving my Wordpress-site from `/portfolio/` to `root`, it still redirects back to `/portfolio/`.

- I followed https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_Directories_On_Your_Existing_Server so I changed the URL's in Settings » General and then moved the whole directory.
- I also tried changing the permalinks to something else.

  - set to *plain*, it redirects to `/portfolio/`,
  - set to *Month and name*, it redirects to `/2017/02/portfolio-website/`.
  - set to my preferred structure, *%category%/%postname%/*, it redirects to `/work/portfolio-website/`

My guess is that it does that because it looks for anything with 'portfolio' in the name.

I have no idea what causes it. 
My .htaccess has the following content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

EDIT:
The URL is: http://aartdenbraber.nl/

Comment: Hi! Do you have the URL of this? And/or could you tell us when the redirect happens? Is it on any link on your homepage, say? Or maybe something more specific?

Comment: Hello, yeah, it's http://aartdenbraber.nl/portfolio/ and the redirect happens when navigating to http://aartdenbraber.nl/. However, when navigating to one of the posts, like http://aartdenbraber.nl/work/the-minimalist-portfolio-template/, it works just fine

Comment: Hmmm - for me http://aartdenbraber.nl/portfolio/ is a "Page not found", and http://aartdenbraber.nl/ doesn't redirect anywhere. (it does have broken images, though...?)

Comment: Yeah it might just be a caching issue. A weird one, though. When I look at it using incognito mode, it displays just fine.

Comment: Yes, it's just a caching issue. One I can't fix on my current browser, though. But it seems to display fine on other browsers. Must have been the heavy testing or something. Thanks for your help!